# vba error - SQL left join issue

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to solve this issue and as it is sql and VBA, thought I would post here. The error shows a left join issue, but not sure if that is a false flag.

```
strSQL = "SELECT USERID AS UserId,APPOINTMENTDATE, isnull ([1],0) as'other',isnull ([2],0) as 'Medicare'" & _
"FROM (SELECT invoices.USERID, APPOINTMENTDATE," & _
"[Total] , PAYERCODE, Users.LOCATIONID" & _
"FROM APPOINTMENTS " & _
"left join INVOICES on recordid = appointmentid inner join users on appointments.userid = users.userid" & _
"where APPOINTMENTDATE between '2017-01-22' and '2017-01-22' " & _
"and invoices.INTERNALID >0 " & _
"and appointments.RECORDSTATUS in (1,3,4) " & _
"and NOT appointments.internalid = 0 " & _
"and not CONSULTATIONTIME = 0 " & _
"and ARRIVALTIME >0 " & _
"and APPOINTMENTID not like '' " & _
") AS SourceTable " & _
"PIVOT " & _
"( " & _
"Sum (Total) " & _
"FOR PAYERCODE IN ([1], [2]) " & _
") AS PivotTable; "
```

I have a number of standard select sql queries working in this excel file, but the pivot is causing the challenge.

As a normal MS error it is very limited - sorry for the lack of crystal balls.. The error says - Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left' 
Cheers

Comment: Sorry, left my Crystal Ball at work, what is the error?

Comment: can you debug.print the statement so it's more readable?

Comment: You're fully qualifying some columns with the table name prefix, and some you are not. I would get into the habit of always giving your tables a relevant alias and using this alias with all columns. Without the error, cannot say for sure but that is one thing I noticed.

Comment: HI All - As a normal MS error it is very limited - sorry for the lack of crystal balls.. The error says - Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'

Comment: You are definitely missing a space behind `LOCATIONID`. Therefore `FROM` is not recognized and therefore `LEFT JOIN` comes unexpected.

Comment: Actually: make that several spaces at some of your line continuations (WHERE).

Comment: HI Locengineer . You hit the nail on the head. I knew it would be a space somewhere or a slight misplaced letter. So that fixed it. Can someone tell me or send me a link on how to use the debug.print . as I am unsure what this does.

Comment: Just put a line `Debug.Print strSQL` after this as well as a `Stop` to halt execution. Then hit CTRL+G to see the immediate window in VBA Editor. You will see your concatenated strSQL value there and can look for further mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no space after `LOCATIONID`, so the result of this

```
"[Total] , PAYERCODE, Users.LOCATIONID" & _
"FROM APPOINTMENTS " & _
"left join ..."
```

is this:

```
[Total] , PAYERCODE, Users.LOCATIONIDFROM APPOINTMENTS left join ...
```

So you have a botched `FROM`, causing `left` to be not understood or expected at that position.